# PHP code won't run on CentOS like on Debian

Tags: debian, centos

I have a Debian machine running Apache and PHP 5. I have a website that runs very well, no database back-end just plain PHP.

I am trying to move that PHP website to a CentOS based machine. But I am getting all kind of strange errors.

What is the difference besides `apache2` and `httpd`. How can I make it work without code modifications?

Comment: While JakeGould's answer is extremely helpful, unless you provide us more detail, this question seems more suited on Stackoverflow since it involves programming errors.  If you can provide a few of those errors we might be able to explain the reason you are getting those errors.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the specific errors you are running into, this is not easy to diagnose. But I am confident this has 100% nothing to do with one system being CentOS and another being Debian; PHP code runs on any system that can run PHP code.

All that said, you state this:

> What is the difference besides `apache2` and `httpd`. How can I make
>   it work without code modifications?

There is 100% no difference between `apache2` and `httpd` name-wise between Debian (`apache2`) and CentOS (`httpd`). Those are simply system binary names and the CentOS/RedHat/Fedora core development team seems to prefer the more generic `httpd` moniker for Apache rather than the brand-specific `apache2`.

Knowing that, I am fairly confident that if this is a PHP code issue it has 100% nothing to do with Apache. Rather, there might be issues with the installed versions of PHP 5 running on each machine.

For example, code that runs well in PHP 5.1 won’t necessarily run well in PHP 5.2, 5.3, 5.4, etc… Each minor and major number release of PHP is backwards compatible with earlier versions of PHP, but there might be very slight changes in code functionality that would cause PHP 5.3 code to choke on PHP 5.4.

In fact in my personally experience, many of the sites I manage are staying at PHP 5.3 right now until core PHP code updates are made to make the code “play nice” with PHP 5.4. These changes involve just adjusting a few core functions to accommodate interface/core-function changes between PHP 5.3 and 5.4 but that’s about it; no rush to deal with it just yet because the core OS these systems are on natively have PHP 5.3 installed and work fine.

I would recommend you comparing the PHP Apache plugin version numbers by checking the output of [`phpinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) on both servers and seeing what versions are installed and being used on each. To do this just create a file on each server’s webroot called `phpinfo.php` like this; I’m using [`nano`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nano) as a text editor but feel free to use whatever text editor you prefer:

```
nano /var/www/phpinfo.php
```

Also note I am using `/var/www/` as your webroot path; be sure to change that to match your actual system’s webroot.

Now just place the following code in that `phpinfo.php` file:

```
<?php

// Show all information, defaults to INFO_ALL
phpinfo();

?>
```

Now load that `phpinfo.php` via a webbrowser via a URL like this; change the hostname to match your system’s actual hostname:

```
http://localhost/phpinfo.php
```

Right at the top of the page will be a big purple banner that tells you exactly what version of PHP you are using like this one which clearly shows the system I am testing on is using PHP version 5.4.10:

[image: "phpinfo()" example PHP version 5.4.10 banner.]

Note that while most installed versions of PHP potentially have a command line interpreter, that PHP command line interpreter has 100% nothing to do with the Apache PHP plugin version. So the output of `php -v` will only give you info on the installed PHP command line interpreter; `phpinfo()` is what you should always use to confirm/check the version of your actual web server is running.